# I don't understand the for loop with this prime number checker

Tags: c, for-loop, primes

I don't understand how this checks for prime numbers:

```
int n,f;
  
printf("");
scanf("%d",&n);

int p=0;

for (f=1;f<=n;f++)
{
   if (n%f==0)
   {
     p=p+1;
   }
}

if (p==2)
{
   printf("prime");
}
else
{
   printf("not prime");
}
```

**What is p=0, p=p+1, and p==2? Where did these assignments/comparisons come from?**

Comment: https://atechdaily.com/posts/algorithm-for-Prime-Number

Comment: "_What is p=0 p=p+1,and p==2 where it came from ?_" - Did you write the program? If you didn't, can't you ask the person who did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is basically checking all the factors of the input number, including 1 and the number itself. Primes are by definition any number that has no other factor other than itself and 1, so if the 'p' factor term equals 2 it means the number is prime because the increment has happened at 1 and the number only.